# aws ec2: ssh to instance created by other user with no pem file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need ssh into aws instance that has been started by another user. 
The key-pair file has not been shared with me, however valid account credentials, access to aws console and key/secret-key has been provided.

What I understand is that there is no way to download pem file from aws console.
Is there any way to  re-create pem file via amazon cli using key/secret-key?

Comment: easy way 
1. stop instance, 2. create snapshot 3. create new instance from snapshot with new key-pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keypair security mechanism is implemented in Linux, not by AWS. Therefore, there is no way to use AWS credentials to login to an instance without a PEM file.

However, some alternatives:

- If the AMI used is fairly recent, and the correct permissions are assigned, you might be able to use [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) to login to the instance, totally bypassing the need for a private key
- If the AMI used is fairly recent, you might be able to [Connect Using EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html), which allows you to temporarily push a new keypair to the instance
- You could create an AMI of the instance, then launch a new instance from the AMI while specifying a keypair. This will put the new keypair into `/home/ec2-user/.aws/authorized_keys`, allowing it to be used to login.
- If you don't want to create a new instance, you could:

  - Stop the instance
  - Detach the boot volume
  - Attach the boot volume it to another instance
  - Add a new keypair to the `/home/ec2-user/.aws/authorized_keys` file on that volume
  - Detach the volume
  - Reattach it to the original instance
  - Start the instance